# How to configure Mathjax in Python Django

Tags: django, mathjax

I would like to know how to configure Mathjax in Django in a Q&A system where Questions and Answers will be based on LaTeX format.

I have tried to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

into the html template where the questions and answers will be displayed to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the page's content is dynamically created, you will need to call MathJax after the content has been loaded.  See [the documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/typeset.html) for details.  The main idea is that you have to include

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

in the javascript that is executed after the content is in place.

Comment: Hi, the contents are retrieved from the database and I've tried:                                                         <script type="text/javascript"
   src="/mathjax/config/TeX-AMS_HTML.js">
</script>                                                             but that does not work also. I'm puzzled.

Comment: When you add new content to the page after MathJax has already typeset it the first time, as it sounds like you are doing here when you retrieve data from the database, you need to tell MathJax to re-typeset the page.  In the javascript that adds the new content to the page, you should include the command that I list above.  See the documentation link that I include above in order to see more details about the process.

Comment: Hi, I have figured out that in the html page, in the <div> tag, and if there is a <pre> tag, Mathjax does not work where maths formulas are within the <pre> tag. Is there a workaround solution instead of removing the <pre> tag? Thanks.

Comment: You are right, MathJax does not process the contents of `<pre>` or `<code>` tags.  You can remove `pre` from the `skipTags` array in your configuration.  See the [tex2jax configuration options](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/options/tex2jax.html) documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

fOR **Dynamic content** here's is the working solution. I used AsciiMath Input as the input format in mathjax that incorporates [ASCIIMathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AsciiMath). 
In the base.html add the following scripts:

```
<script>
  MathJax = {
    loader: {load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml']}
  }
</script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/startup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
```

and remember to enclose the dynamic text by back-ticks”, i.e., `...` So in the django-admin you can simply enter sqrt(50) as ` sqrt(50) ` or ` x^2 ` and the dynamic content which is passed from view to the template, in the template you surround {{e1}} by back-ticks

### ` {{ e1 }} `

instead of
    {{ e1 }} where e1 is the dynamic content. So if e1 which was earlier displayed in plain text as 2*sqrt(2) will now be displyed as 2√2.

For more details: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/asciimath.html#asciimath-support

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html. For the demo indicated [here](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) to work you should also add `['\(', '\)']` to inlineMath:

```js
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
  },
  svg: {
    fontCache: 'global'
  }
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
</script>
```